# Connect to local MS SQL Server from .NET 6 API running in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API running in docker and I want to connect to local SQL Server database (not dockerized!), but I'm unable to do so. Connecting to a database on remote server by IP works fine, but using connection string like

```
var dbHost = "COM-3195\\IMRANMSSQL";
var dbName = "CustomersDb";
var dbPassword = "prg@321654";
var connectionString = $"Data Source={dbHost};Initial Catalog={dbName};User Id=sa;Password={dbPassword}";
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CustomerWebService/CustomerWebService.csproj", "CustomerWebService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CustomerWebService/CustomerWebService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CustomerWebService"
RUN dotnet build "CustomerWebService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CustomerWebService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CustomerWebService.dll"]
```

My Docker-Compsoe.yml

```
services:
  customerwebservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}customerwebservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: CustomerWebService/Dockerfile
    extra_hosts:
      - "COM-3195\\IMRANMSSQL:<IP>"
```

My application is not connecting to the database, and showing this in the log:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://[::]:443
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app/
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.5 initialized 'CustomerDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.5' with options: None
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'master' on server '<IP>,1433'.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

It is working fine if I am running without docker, if I do like this  in my `composer.yml` file

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  backend:
services:
  customerdb:
    container_name: customer-db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=prg@321654
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 8001:1433 
  customerwebapi:
    container_name: cutomer-api
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}customerwebapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: CustomerWebAPI/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 8002:80 
    environment:
      - DB_HOST= customerdb
      - DB_NAME= CustomersDb
      - DB_SA_PASSWORD=prg@321654
```

It is working fine but it's running on local,8001 in SQL Server, but I want my local SQL Server to add.

Please help, I just started learning Dockering.

Please help me connect to SQL Server database (not dockerized) from my Docker image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access something on the host, you can add a name for the `host-gameway` in the `extra_hosts` section. The usual thing is to call it `host.docker.internal`, so we'll do that here as well.

Then you need to change the database hostname to `host.docker.internal` and you should be able to connect.

I'm a little confused as to how you specify the database host name in your program. In the C# snippet, you show a hard-coded value. But in the docker-compose file where you run the database in a container, you set an environment variable. The 'nice' thing to do is to handle it via an environment variable, so I'll show that solution here

```
services:
  customerwebservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}customerwebservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: CustomerWebService/Dockerfile
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
```

Comment: It worked but i want to know how it is getting my database ? when my connection string is
```
var dbHost = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_HOST");//"COM-3195\\IMRANMSSQL";
var dbName = "CustomersDb";
var dbPassword = "prg@321654";
var connectionString = $"Data Source={dbHost};Initial Catalog={dbName};User Id=sa;Password={dbPassword}";
```

Comment: i comment out my server info and took environment host then how it is getting my server. i am really confused about those two line in service, 
Please help me understand.
```
extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
```

Comment: On Docker for Windows and Mac, `host.docker.internal` is already defined and you can use that to reach the host. It's not defined on Linux though. By adding the extra_hosts line, you ensure that `host.docker.internal` is always defined, no matter what platform you run on, and can be used to reach the host. When it's defined, you use it as a host name, just like you'd use www.google.com, mydomain.com or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You have the two following solutions:

1. Get the IP from your host as part of the virtual network that docker has created.

   - Use commands like `docker inspect <container_id>`, `docker network ls` and `docker network inspect <network_id>` to receive the IP address of the "Gateway"
   - This IP can be found with `docker network inspect ...` at `IPAM > Config > Gateway`
2. Use the IP of your host e.g. from `eth0`. I am not 100% sure, but you should also be able to use at least the IP-Adress from your main network interface.

Just as a general information, even if your container and the DB are running on the same host, you cannot use `localhost` as this is being resolved to different systems (once for the container, once for the host itself)